# How can we take user input for long integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-integer

I am appending values in an array which should contain long integers.
So, how can I take user inputs for it, as overflow error is shown.

```
from array import *
import math

n = int(input())
arr = array('l',[])
for i in range (n):
    x = int(input())

    arr.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the input()
Your problem is:
python can handle integers of infinte size, C's datatype long cant:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types

arr = array('l',[])
If you don't need to use datatypes from C, just use a list.
Else you can look for a datatype whoch can handle bigger numbers.

Comment: yeah, using list works but the requirement is to do using an array. Can you suggest datatype which can be used?

Comment: @AyushLal: The various C data-type codes available are listed in the `array` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array).